# How would one go about making this grid clickable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, grid, clickable

I've created the grid below using a canvas as well as lines going through it, how would one go about making this grid clickable?

The ideal result would be when I click one of the boxes it turns yellow, and a value inside an array would be changed from 0 to 1. I'm fairly certain I know how to set up a 2D array but that is the general idea. Thanks for any help.

```
var cellCount=20;
var currentGrid = new Array(cellCount).fill().map(() => new Array(cellCount).fill(0));
var nextGrid = new Array(cellCount).fill().map(() => new Array(cellCount).fill(0));

for(var i=0;i<20;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<20;j++){
        currentGrid[i][j]=0;
        nextGrid[i][j]=0;
    }
}

var canvas=document.getElementById('grid');
var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');



function drawGrid(h,w,id){
    for(var x=0;x<w;x++){
        ctx.moveTo(0,x*20);
        ctx.lineTo(h,x*20);
        ctx.lineWidth=1;
        ctx.strokeStyle='rgb(211,211,211)';
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    for(var y=0;y<h;y++){
        ctx.moveTo(y*20,0);
        ctx.lineTo(y*20,w);
        ctx.lineWidth=1;
        ctx.strokeStyle='rgb(211,211,211)';
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}

function getPosition(event)
  {

    if (event.x != undefined && event.y != undefined)
    {
      x = event.x;
      y = event.y;
    }

  }

  canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", getPosition, false);

drawGrid(421,421,'grid');
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you provided, it appears there is no loop, meaning there will be no other updates to the grid visually.  Also, the draw function appears that it would draw offscreen, as you are multiplying your values by 20, which should probably be cellCount.

First I would recommend setting up a 'game loop'. A pattern that involves updating and drawing in a loop:

```
function loop(tick) {
  update(tick);
  draw(tick);
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
// start the loop
requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

Then you'll need to define the update and draw function.  In this example you may not have anything to update yet, but you might in the future.  The draw function would first erase the background and then draw the grid:

```
function draw(tick) {
  // clear background
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // draw the grid
  drawGrid(numCols, numRows);
}
```

Now you'll need to define numCols and numRows which is simply the width or height divided by the cellSize.  This tells you how many cells in the height and width of the canvas.  I see you have cellCount instead of cellSize, but cellSize can be calculated the opposite way by taking canvas height (or width) and dividing it by cellCount (assuming the canvas is square).

```
 var numCols = Math.floor(canvas.width / cellSize);
 var numRows = Math.floor(canvas.height / cellSize);
```

As for the click handler; you'll want to figure out which cell they clicked in by dividing the x and y you've captured by the cellSize.

```
 // assuming x and y are the coordinates on the canvas where the user clicked
 var cellX = Math.floor(x / cellSize);
 var cellY = Math.floor(y / cellSize);
 // now set the cell
 nextGrid[cellY][cellX] = 1;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. So I've added everything you've suggested and it works (with just one error saying the update(tick) doesn't work, but that's alright for now. My next issue would be getting the cells to toggle colour and value, from 0 to 1 and from black to yellow as well as vice versa. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Additionally, I think that would be done by using

`if(nextGrid[cellY][cellX] == 0){
         nextGrid[cellY][cellX] == 1;
        }
        else if(nextGrid[cellY][cellX] == 1){
         nextGrid[cellY][cellX] == 0; 
        }`

correct?

Comment: when drawing the cells, you can just use the value to dictate colour.  for example: var isCellSelected=nextGrid[cellY][cellX] == 1; ctx.fillStyle = isCellSelected ? 'blue' : 'white'; ctx.fillRect(cellX*cellSize, cellY*cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by that, sorry, two things, where should that go in my code and what exactly is that doing?